# QuickCheck for Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, quickcheck

Is there a version of quickcheck that works for Javascript and that is well maintained? I have found several such as check.js and claire, but none of them seem to support shrinking of failing test cases, which has always struck me as the most useful part of the whole problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm creator of [jsverify](https://github.com/phadej/jsverify). I'll try constantly to make it better, bug reports and feature requests are welcomed.

There are also a list of other javascript generative testing libraries in a readme. So far I haven't found any other good alternative to the jsverify.

Comment: Hey, in jsverify it says "Write properties about your function that should hold true for all inputs".  How then do you test functions with if/else decisions?  What if for example I want to test that when a string contains "foo", that the function does something?

Comment: @JK. John Hughes has  advice on specifying properties at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0NUOst-53U. ScottW has suggestions at https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/property-based-testing-2/. I can recommend them, if you can grok the Haskell and F# syntax (the verbal explanations really help).

Answer (score 8):

I recently released https://github.com/dubzzz/fast-check

I built it in order to answer several limitations I encountered in the existing quickcheck implementations in JavaScript.

It comes natively with a shrink feature which can shrink even combination of arbitraries (the frameworks I tried were failing on oneof like arbitraries).
It also can generate large objects and arrays. 
By default it tends to try smaller values first in order to detect trivial edge cases while it covers all the possible inputs in next runs.
Lots of other features are on-going or already available :)

Cheers,
Nicolas

Comment: it's rare that I read through all the documentation at once for a library, but with yours I have! Can't wait to give this a bash. I've used and really enjoy JsVerify, so I'm very much looking forward to fast-check

Answer (score 4):

I wrote [quick_check.js](https://github.com/gampleman/quick_check.js), which has a nice library of generators. Shrinking is not there yet, but is planned.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a dearth of good quickcheck-like testing tools in javascript.  However they are to be better supported in typed languages, and in fact you can write your tests in one of those languages if you wish.

To avoid dealing with runtime interop, I'd recommend going with a language which compiles to JS and runs on node.js (eg: [Purescript with purescript-quickcheck](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-quickcheck)), or a java-based language using the Nashorn engine provided in Java 8, for example [ScalaCheck](https://jazmit.github.io/2015/01/10/scalacheck-nashorn.html).  You could even use [ghcjs](https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs) and the original flavor of the quickcheck library!

Comment: These days I am using elm, as my interest in JavaScript is 100% about in browser operations. For backend code I use erlang

Comment: I was going to include Elm and https://github.com/TheSeamau5/QuickCheck in my answer, but PureScript integrates better with javascript (at least until Elm 0.16..)

Comment: @jazmit there's a more recent property based testing library from the same author for Elm: https://github.com/TheSeamau5/elm-check